# Share button to google+

Tags: php

I am using fb sharer on my website now. I wanted to know how to provide a button for google+ share. I searched but could not find proper info. Can any1 share some link or code to do it.

Comment: y did it get negative ranking??? whts wrong with the question?

Comment: Possibly because you haven't take the time to search on Google before asking here :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has a [web page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/index.html) that will assist you with adding the +1 button.

Answer (score 2):

Here

http://wprockers.com/how-to-add-google-1-plus-one-share-button-in-my-website-blog-862.html